# How to use Androids location package in a service separate from the User Interface thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, location

I have a small Android app that I have been working on that logs GPS data to my SD card in a GPX file.  I currently have a main Activity that starts a Service to do all the background work.  The service is kept in the foreground in the notification bar to make it the least likely thing to be killed by the OS.  Currently I am requesting location updates from the service at the maximum frequency to get the most accurate route.  The problem I am having is my User Interface is acting slow/strange.  Correct me if I am wrong, but what I have concluded is that I have too much going on in the main thread of the app.  My next thought is to try and move the service performing the acquiring and logging of data to a separate thread.  I am new to Java/Android so the whole topic of interacting with separate threads is hard for me to wrap my head around.  Initially in research I came across IntentServices, which are supposed to make threading easier, but from what I read these don’t seem to mix well with the Android location package because they don’t run long enough.  I feel like I am running in circles with internet searches on this topic.  I desperately need some guidance on how to achieve the following features for my programs service:

1. Separate thread from Main Thread
2. Fetching and storing of data must be the least likely thing to be killed by the OS and run indefinitely once started (don’t worry about battery I will have the device plugged in to power while running the app)
3. Eventually I will need the ability to interact with the User Interface

Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: ComponentName startService (Intent service)

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService(android.content.Intent)

Answer (score 1):

this is a common problem that i have accomplished a lot on

in the launcher or main() ( what Android is calling an Activity ) you do as little as possible ( which amounts to saving the the refs they give you and maybe setting a few other things as long as you are there ) and do ^not^ drop in to a long-running activity

A Service is exactly what you need but instead of trying to pump it into a "hold on to it" state what you do is implement checks for nulls and handle as needed -- trying to "fix" a machine to make it run the way you want here actually involves rescinding you hold on the main thread and letting it go as fast as consistent with the Applicaton's general constraints.

To do this you can simply write a Service - reading everything available - then extend that service and implement Runnable then you run the constructor on that code from the Activity Constructor and do new Thead(yourClass).start(); in the onCreate() checking for Thread.isRunning() before starting it again ...

Service will have an onCompletion() call in it somewhere - it will go through an interface

All this is done in Android in something like start activity for result then you just to the UI stuff in that call or sorta figure out a way for the GUI to get called somehow at some time then check to see if Service is done an so report in the gui